# Google Maps: render unique polygons based on ID

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

**Short version**

In Google Maps API, how do I use unique polygon ID correctly so that I don't get duplicate polygons rendered on top of each other?

**Long version**

I want to layer geographical heatmap data on top of Google Maps. The heatmap consists of square tiles. I obtain the tile coordinates along with their ID and score from my API server in JSON format. When the page loads, I render the heatmap tiles as Polygon objects and they are displayed correctly, but if I drag the map half way so that some of the tiles are still visible, the same tiles (along with new ones) are re-fetched from the server and rendered on top of existing tiles. This causes color change and ruins the heatmap.
I am adding unique integer IDs coming from the API server as IDs in Polygon objects but it does not solve the issue and I don't understand why.

**Here is the code** (for brevity, only the related part is shown):

```
function initMap() {
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(37.461021, -122.163314);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {center: center, zoom: 11});

    /* 'bounds_changed' event happens too frequently
     better to use 'idle' event that fires when map changed and now is idle.
    */
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', redrawMap);
}
function redrawMap() {
    /* redraw map's heatmap tiles and pollution sources */
    var mapBounds = map.getBounds();
    var ne = mapBounds.getNorthEast();
    var sw = mapBounds.getSouthWest();
    var url = 'https://<my_api_server/dev/map_data' +
            '?ne_lat=' + ne.lat() + '&ne_lng=' + ne.lng() + '&sw_lat=' + sw.lat() + '&sw_lng=' + sw.lng();
    /* get data from API server */
    $.getJSON({
        url: url,
        success: function(result, status, xhr){
            mapData = result;
            // fetched JSON contains 'tiles' key with all the data in the value
            var tileData = mapData['tiles']; 
            addHeatmapTiles(tileData);
        }
    });
}
function addHeatmapTiles(tileData) {
    /* show heatmap tiles for sources on the map */
    var num_tiles = tileData.length;
    for(var c = 0; c < num_tiles; c++){
        var tile = tileData[c];
        var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
            id: tile['id'],
            fillColor: colors[tile['score']], // colors is a hash with score->color values
            fillOpacity: 0.6,
            map: map,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            paths: tile['tile_coords']
        });
    }
}
```

**Sample JSON data coming from the server:**

```
{  
   "tiles":[  
      {  
         "id":63125,
         "tile_coords":[  
            {"lat":37.446584, "lng":-122.129749},
            {"lat":37.439548, "lng":-122.127375},
            {"lat":37.437663, "lng":-122.136237},
            {"lat":37.444699, "lng":-122.138612}
         ],
         "score":8
      },
      {  
         "id":60830,
         "tile_coords":[  
            {"lat":37.447649, "lng":-122.158945},
            {"lat":37.440613, "lng":-122.156571},
            {"lat":37.438728, "lng":-122.165433},
            {"lat":37.445764, "lng":-122.167808}
         ],
         "score":8
      },
   ],
   "other_data": "..."
}
```

---

P.S. I admit I am a backend guy and just learned JavaScript for this task but I spent days on trying different ways and it still does not work. I am getting desperate and would appreciate any help.

I would also appreciate any additional suggestions about optimizing this code. For instance, would it be faster to abandon this and use `google.maps.Data.loadGeoJson()` instead? I tried it but neither it rendered any tile nor it returned any error. If this deserves separate post, please suggest and I will create one with provided code snippet.

Comment: Maybe you can use an array or ES2015 [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) class to store the IDs you have already added to the map. So before Polygon creation just check if ID is already in this array or Set.

Comment: @xomena , my other ideas did not work so I resorted to your proposed solution. Thanks!